# Passing two date in a Function using udf getting error of df.show() in pyspark (similar to apply function in pandas)

Tags: python, apache-spark, date, pyspark, user-defined-functions

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
data = [("1","2019-07-01","2019-02-03"),("2","2019-06-24","2019-03-21"),("3","2019-08-24","2020-08-24")]
df=spark.createDataFrame(data=data,schema=["id","date1",'date2'])
df.show()
```

[image: Input Data frame]

**Expected Output**
[image: Output data]

I tried with below code :

```
    from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
    import pyspark.sql.functions as sf
    def get_datediff(vec):
        d1=vec[0];d2=vec[1]
        rt=datediff(d1,d2)
        return(rt)
    df = df.withColumn('date_diff1', sf.udf(get_datediff)(array('date1','date2')))
df.show()
```

But i am getting Below Error , unable to get date diff.

[image: getting Error]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Spark SQL functions, you don't need to define a UDF. Just call the function directly, e.g.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

data = [("1","2019-07-01","2019-02-03"),("2","2019-06-24","2019-03-21"),("3","2019-08-24","2020-08-24")]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data,schema=["id","date1",'date2'])
df2 = df.withColumn('date_diff1', F.datediff('date1','date2'))

df2.show()
+---+----------+----------+----------+
| id|     date1|     date2|date_diff1|
+---+----------+----------+----------+
|  1|2019-07-01|2019-02-03|       148|
|  2|2019-06-24|2019-03-21|        95|
|  3|2019-08-24|2020-08-24|      -366|
+---+----------+----------+----------+
```

---

If you insist on using UDF, you can do this:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from datetime import datetime

data = [("1","2019-07-01","2019-02-03"),("2","2019-06-24","2019-03-21"),("3","2019-08-24","2020-08-24")]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data,schema=["id","date1",'date2'])

@F.udf('int')
def datediff_udf(d1, d2):
    d1 = datetime.strptime(d1, "%Y-%m-%d")
    d2 = datetime.strptime(d2, "%Y-%m-%d")
    return (d1 - d2).days

df2 = df.withColumn('date_diff1', datediff_udf('date1', 'date2'))
```

Comment: i agree , if in case i want to use with udf how to go about . just want udf code . i am replicating the code as same as python .

Comment: @F.udf('int') . may i know why we define this separatetly

Comment: it's just a matter of style. you can do it in your way, e.g. remove `@F.udf('int')` and use `df2 = df.withColumn('date_diff1', F.udf(datediff_udf)('date1', 'date2'))`